# What is the key scheme and encoding used in GUN?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption, gun

What are the key schemes, sizes, and encodings used in [GUN db](https://gun.eco/docs/API)?

I didn't find a quick answer on searching so am adding the question here.

The keys look like:

```
let lee = await SEA.pair()
>lee.pub
```

`"wfcQUDB44NhKFikH4NhWKVZfhQY-xGRpwnZIHjgmwRI.xLxhMgWvgvYHCc95L6Ni2RLmjJCMowWNbR3eQ1r4MOU"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For Signing/Verifying:**

Gun uses [ECDSA with the P-256 curve](https://github.com/amark/gun/blob/8e4128b474987fe59e2d73e38c56e30b8a4aa291/sea/settings.js#L6).

The keys are [encoded](https://github.com/amark/gun/blob/8e4128b474987fe59e2d73e38c56e30b8a4aa291/sea/settings.js#L23) in [base64](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64).

More specifically, the public key is a [`.` delineated concatenation of the `x` and `y` output parameters](https://github.com/amark/gun/blob/2168e3e2d729076818f3a0b5730839148f9ee939/sea/pair.js#L30) from running [`exportKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/exportKey) on a JSON web key (JWK) [`CryptoKeyPair`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CryptoKeyPair)  object obtained from the [`subtleCrypto.exportKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/exportKey) function (following key generation using [`subtleCrypto.generateKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CryptoKeyPair) with ECDSA P256 curve).

[This](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/80139/30574) has an overview of the `x` and `y` params.

**For Encryption/Decryption:**

Gun uses ECDH P-256 cruve with same process as above (public keys stored as `lee.epub` for OP example)

Comment: Wow! AMAZING answer.